# MySQL Workbench: Start Transaction seems to be committed before rollback

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wrote a bunch of delete statements and wrapped them in a transaction:

```
start transaction;
delete a...
delete b...
delete c...
rollback;
```

The idea is I would want the deletes to occur inside a transaction which would rollback upon completion. If a step failed along the way, I would want the successful steps to be rolled back as well.

To my chagrin `delete a` worked, removing a few thousand rows, `delete b` failed, but when I reran the statements all the records from **a** appeared to be gone.

Is this because the transaction is still open? I tried doing:

```
set session transaction isolation level read committed;
select a.*
```

and got back zero rows so I think that is not the case. Was the successful `a` delete committed? And if so, how do I prevent that from happening until I can guarantee a full working query?

Comment: Make sure you turn off `autoCommit`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL Workbench enables auto commit by default. In the SQL editor there is a toolbar button that can be used to toggle auto commit at will:

[image]

Comment: Pointing out these features is great, I definitely learned something. However, I think that this answer does not really address the main thing that went wrong for the OP, as `start transaction` effectively turns off (an internal version of) auto commit until the transaction is complete, see also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77403141/1381569)

Answer (score 1):

Somebody turned me on to, what I think, is a better way to do this:

```
begin;
<sql transactions>
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the autocommit flag to false:

```
set @@autocommit = false;
start transaction;
delete a...
delete b...
delete c...
rollback;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably the transaction was still open. `rollback` is not executed if there is an error in a line above it. So long as the the transaction is not rolled back, it will seem (when using `SELECT`) that the data has been deleted, but since you have not committed the transaction, you can still use `rollback`.

**Long version**

To verify that this answer is correct, you can do the following

```
start transaction;
delete a...
SELECT @@non_existent_variableXYZ -- This gives an error
rollback;
```

Now run `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_TRX`. You can see the transaction in progress. Then run `rollback` (in a script that does not give an error, consider creating a new query tab in MySQL Workbench). You will see that the deletion is undone and by running using SELECT again you can see that the transaction is no longer in `information_schema.INNODB_TRX`.

**About other answers**

This answer shows that you don't need to set `@@autocommit` to `0` to be able to group multiple statements into a transaction and to be able to roll it back with `rollback`.