UNDO in SQL workbench
i run a query to update the data the query gone wrong and data is updated not as per my desired output.
Now i want to get that previous data back.
what should i do?
I tried ROLLBACK function it didn't worked.
also tried doing autocommit off, that was not even recognized by workbench. shwon a syntax error.

Use START TRANSACTION; to start a transaction. You can't use ROLLBACK if there's no transaction in progress.

Related (maybe duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400283/mysql-workbench-start-transaction-seems-to-be-committed-before-rollback

I suggest you use the "mysqlbinlog" tool.
I have used this before to recover data.

you can see this page
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
